# How do I use roloxstudio offline?

Tags: roblox

How do I disable the script check in the robloxstudio?

Normally you can't run any script in offline mode, because the robloxstudio wants to check it before, and if you don't have internet, it is a long delay on running it.

I remember that I fixed it before, by editing a file, but I don't remember where.

Answer (score 0):

You just open it normally and make sure you have your game saved to your hard drive. You won't be able to see most textures and decals though.

Comment: The problem is that scripts needs to be checked by the roblox servers before they are run, if you have no internet then they are delayed 1-3 minutes, which is quite annoying

Comment: I've never had that problem - My studio has always worked offline and it doesn't check the scripts.